# Using double cream in icing

Tags: food-preservation, cream, icing

I'm looking at a recipe for icing that uses double cream as the substrate for the icing.

How well will the cream be preserved on a 1:4 (or better, given its application) mix?

Also, how well would such icing set? I'm looking for a fairly stiff mix that will retain peaks; can I expect such with cream as the substrate?

Comment: Well, I abandoned the double cream recipe and went, instead, for royal icing. It has the solidity I need and the added advantage of being used as a 'glue' for other bits of the cake. It all worked out well. (Just hope I haven't poisoned anyone!)

Answer (score 2):

Just simply use whipped double cream only:

- add a knife point of starch and a few grains of vanilla per ¼L of double cream
- whip it (not too much or it'll turn into butter)
- pour into a piping bag
- refrigerate overnight

and it'll remain stiff enough so you can create anything you want including flowers:

[image: Piping bag]

Comment: That's beautiful. Is that one of yours? I'll give it a go.

Comment: Nope, that's a pic I got when looking for "Piping bag"... Also: Don't whip it too much or you'll end up with butter easily.. @Paul (answer edited)

Comment: Now I am confused. I thought that "1:4 mix" and "I ended up using royal icing" meant that the OP wanted to make something of the consistency of royal icing, but whipped cream has the consistency of buttercream. Are you sure you are talking about the same thing?

Comment: Refrigerated whipped double cream is not identical to royal icing indeed, but my understanding of OP's question was that he wanted *something different* from royal icing and so I gave him the alternative of something simple like double whipped cream with a bit of starch added (I use corn, but potato works too) and can take some sugar if the vanilla in itself isn't "sweet" enough for him.  Up to him to try out next time and come back and [accept](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer or not...  @rumtscho

Comment: Thanks for posting. As stated, I went for the royal icing - it worked very well for the application. This answer doesn't give me everything I was after, really - I was primarily interested in the longevity of the product, and whether it would last a reasonable amount of time (2 weeks plus, though I never specified a time limit). As pointed out by @rumtscho, I was looking more for specifics than alternatives.

Comment: Sorry to have been of absolutely no help then, though I hope the creamy flowers made you smile so you got *something* out of this answer...  **;-) :-)** @Paul

Comment: @Fabby: Ha! No, it's not like that. You've certainly given me ideas for future ventures, and yes - the pic was great! ;o)